# Inject Code Behind Element Into XAML Data Template

Tags: c#, wpf

As the title suggests I'm looking to inject a code behind element into a data template to be rendered at runtime.

Here is the piece of my XAML code I'd like to inject the code behind element into:

```
<TabControl x:Name="tcDocuments" DockPanel.Dock="Top">
    <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                <Button Content="x" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
   </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
   <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>
           (INSERT CLASS BELOW'S CONTENT PROPERTY HERE)
       </DataTemplate>
   </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
</TabControl>
```

And here is the class that I will be adding to the TabControl above's Items:

```
public class DocumentTab
{
    public string File { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public RichTextBox Content { get; set; }
}
```

Then every time I add a new DocumentTab object to the TabControl's Item list, The RichTextBox property "Content" is inserted into the DataTemplate tag.

I guess the real question here is is this possible?

Cheers.

Comment: Will it always be a DocumentTab? Could you just bind the TabControl's ItemsSource to an ObservableCollection<DocumentTab>, and have the DataTemplate be a RichTextBox? You'd need to change the data type of Content.

Comment: You can put a ContentControl in the DataTemplate and set the Content property of that to a binding to the Content property of DocumentTab, or whatever model has a Content property. This allows you to use any class that has a Content property

Comment: You usually should not reference UI elements (`RichTextBox`) in your models.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put a ContentControl in your DataTemplate like this:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding Content}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

You just have to make sure whatever that template is in has the proper DataContext or the binding might change.

The benefit to this is that it isn't specific to DocumentTab, you could have any Class with a Content property that is your UIElement.

This [MSDN Documentation on ContentControl.Content](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.content(v=vs.110).aspx) gives you some more information and shows some examples of setting the content to UIElements (though only shown in the code-behind)